# How to select only the second max date from a table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table where the delivery date and order number are stored.

Here i was able to get the order with the max delivery date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.ORDER_NO
FROM DELIVERY D
WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO =112 AND D.DELIVERY_DATE = (SELECT  MAX(D1.DELIVERY_DATE) FROM DELIVERY D1
WHERE D1.CUSTOMER_NO = 112 );
```

Here a single customer may have multiple orders.

Now what i want is to get only the second max date.

By using the above query I was able to get the list of data other than the max delivery date by changing the `=` to `<` and adding `ORDER BY` in the subquery.

But its an entire list but i want only the second max date.

Someone pls tell me how I can get only the second max date.

Note: I have tried using `ROWNUM<=1` but i am getting wrong date

Comment: Are you using Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Removing SQL Server tag since `ROWNUM` is a Oracle feature

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i am using Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT D.ORDER_NO
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT D.ORDER_NO,D.DELIVERY_DATE,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by D.DELIVERY_DATE desc) RowNo
FROM DELIVERY D
WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO =1128158 
ORDER BY D.DELIVERY_DATE DESC)
t WHERE t.RowNo = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Oracle:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT t.*, rownum rnum
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT D.ORDER_NO
        FROM DELIVERY D
        WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO = 112
        ORDER BY D.DELIVERY_DATE DESC
    ) t
    WHERE rownum <= 2
)
WHERE rnum >= 2
```

Comment: When i run the sub query alone i am getting 4 rows, but when i run the entire query i am getting 0 result. Whereas if I change the `ROWNUM=1` I am getting 1 row.

Comment: Hi This works perfectly, but i just modified your query by using the `ROW_NUMBER()` function from `@Munna Extreme`'s answer and it works too

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT D.ORDER_NO, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by D.DELIVERY_DATE desc) RowNo
FROM DELIVERY D
WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO =112
) t where t.RowNo = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_NO FROM DELIVERY WHERE CUSTOMER_NO=112 AND DELIVERY_DATE =
(SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_DATE) FROM DELIVERY WHERE CUSTOMER_NO=112 AND 
DELIVERY_DATE<(SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_DATE) FROM DELIVERY AND CUSTOMER_NO=112));
```

The sub query will return second max delivery date which will give order_no of second max date.

Answer (score 1):

**Select Second max date From table**

```
 SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl_date WHERE date NOT IN (SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl_date )
        OR
        SELECT DISTINCT date FROM tbl_date  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1,1;
        OR
        SELECT MAX(date) FROM ( SELECT date FROM tbl_date  MINUS SELECT MAX(date) FROM tbl_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT TOP 1 D.ORDER_NO
FROM DELIVERY D WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO =112 
 AND D.DELIVERY_DATE = (SELECT  MAX(D1.DELIVERY_DATE) FROM DELIVERY D1 WHERE D1.CUSTOMER_NO = 112 );
 ORDER BY  DELIVERY_DATE  DESC
```

Answer (score -2):

change `D.DELIVERY_DATE =`

to `D.DELIVERY_DATE <`

```
SELECT DISTINCT D.ORDER_NO
    FROM DELIVERY D
    WHERE D.CUSTOMER_NO =112 AND D.DELIVERY_DATE = (SELECT  MAX(D1.DELIVERY_DATE) FROM DELIVERY D1
    WHERE D1.CUSTOMER_NO = 112 );
```

OR SOMETHING LIKE BELOW

```
SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_DATE)
  FROM TABLE
 WHERE DELIVERY_DATE< ( SELECT MAX(DELIVERY_DATE)
                 FROM TABLE)
```

Comment: Kindly see my question, what you have said has been already done.